# SQL server - contains in case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, contains, sql-like

Could you please help? I have one column with ID and in another table columne where are few IDs in one row separeted with ','

I need something like simple check whether ID is in column 2 or not ...something like:

```
Case When
Column1(123) like Column2(123,345,567)
Then 1
Else 0
END
```

...but this is not working.

Comment: Why don't you store it in a relation table in the first place? You should create a second table which links to this table via foreign-key. There you add those three records. Then you can use `Case When EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.ID=T1.ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: Keeping IDs in a comma separated list can be a real headache and I'd advise you to perhaps redesign your database to proper standards. [You may find this as a solution to your current problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/1200185)

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72292/splitting-a-csv-column-from-select-query-into-multiple-columns/72298#72298

Comment: @Viktor Fix your database design.  It's for your sake.